# Raspberry pi freezed on wifi adapter

Tags: usb, wifi, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a type B Raspberry Pi running perfectly with USB keyboard and USB mouse both plugged in.

However pi freeze in all the following combinations,

1. USB keyboard + [USB wifi adapter](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/products/network-devices/routers/airstationtm/airstation-trade-n-technology-150mbps-usb-2-0-client/) (CUI)
2. USB mouse + [USB wifi adapter](http://www.buffalo-technology.com/en/products/network-devices/routers/airstationtm/airstation-trade-n-technology-150mbps-usb-2-0-client/) (GUI)

In CUI, pi reboots every time I hot plugged in the adapter, and freezes on asking for login id.
If I boot pi with wifi preplugged in, pi also freeze on asking for login id.

In GUI, it does not reboot but freeze when I hot plugged in the adapter.
It is true when I boot pi with preplugged in.

Could someone please advise me how to fix this?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general tech support.

Comment: I am sorry! I thought it was caused by my config.txt and related to the system loaded module.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your raspberry pi does not have beefy enough USB ports to power the wifi adaptor. Get a powered USB hub.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly. It now works perfectly with a powered USB hub.